# Forwarding a TCP connection to another server

Tags: rust, tcp, connection

Lets say I have two game services, a login server and a game server. When a client connects to the login server to be authenticated, if the authentication is successful, I want to transfer them to the game server. This game server is its own service on another host. How would I forward this established TCP connection?

I thought of opening a persisted connection between the two servers and then sending the existing TCP data over, however I am unsure of the next steps to disconnecting the connection between the client and the login while establishing a connection between the client and the game server. Would I send a packet to the client to establish a separate connection to the game server while forwarding the necessary data from the login to the game server? This seems unnecessarily much and potentially unsafe.

The language I am working with is rust, but an abstract answer will also greatly help.

Comment: is the answer "that complicated" is enough for you ? the only simple way I see is never end the connection and just transfer all datas to the other server. But this will be a perf killer over time. I advice you to find a better way like use a jwt, also note that you should also encrypt your data between client and server if you didn't do it already.

Answer (score -2):

The term you're looking for is "proxy".  If you're just passing through the data, there are tools to help with this so that you don't have to do the "donkey work" of managing the TCP-level calls.

[Nginx can do this](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/), and might be a good place to start.

```
stream {
    server {
        listen     12346;
        #TCP traffic will be forwarded to the specified server
        proxy_pass backend.example.com:12346;
    }
}
```

Comment: you didn't understand the question

Comment: OP asked for a way to proxy the connection, even if it is a bad idea.

Comment: OP asking of redirect an already open connection that was already being used for receive data, totally different than directly redirect traffic.